# Docker : starting container process caused "exec: \"-n\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: docker, jmeter, dockerfile

While launching a command on my docker image (run), I get the following error :

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-n\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

The image is an image for Jmeter, that I have created myself :

```
FROM        hauptmedia/java:oracle-java8

MAINTAINER  maisie

ENV         JMETER_VERSION  5.2.1
ENV         JMETER_HOME /opt/jmeter
ENV         JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz

RUN         apt-get clean
RUN         apt-get update
RUN         apt-get -y install ca-certificates              
RUN         mkdir -p ${JMETER_HOME}                         
RUN         cd ${JMETER_HOME}                           
RUN         wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz
RUN         tar -xvzf apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz   
RUN         rm apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz
```

The command that I am launching is :

```
#!/bin/bash

export volume_path=$(pwd)

export jmeter_path="/opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin"

docker run --volume ${volume_path}:${jmeter_path} my/jmeter -n -t ${jmeter_path}/TEST.jmx -l ${jmeter_path}/res.jtl
```

I really can't find any answer to my problem ...

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: What command do you want to run inside the container?

Comment: @BMitch I would like to run the Jmeter command to run Jmeter in non GUI mode, using a file (TEST.jmx) that is on my host machine...

Answer (score 1):

The general form of the `docker run` command is

```
docker run [docker options] <image name> [command]
```

So you are running an image named `amos/jmeter`, and the command you are having it run is `-n -t ...`.  You're getting the error you are because you've only given a list of options and not an actual command.

The first part of this is to include the actual command in your `docker run` line:

```
docker run --rm amos/jmeter \
  jmeter -n ...
```

There's also going to be a problem with how you install the software in the Dockerfile.  (You do not need a `docker run --volume` to supply software that's already in the image.)  Each `RUN` command starts in a new shell in a new environment (in a new container even), so saying *e.g.* `RUN cd ...` in its own line doesn't do anything.  You need to use Dockerfile directives like `WORKDIR` and `ENV` to change the environment.  The `jmeter` command isn't in a standard binary directory so you'll also have a little trouble running it.  I might change:

```sh
# ...

# Run all APT commands in a single command
# (Layer caching can break an install if the list of packages changes)
RUN apt-get clean \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get -y install ca-certificates

# Download and unpack the JMeter tar file
# This is all in a single RUN command, so
# (1) the `cd` at the effect has (temporary) effect, and
# (2) the tar file isn't committed to an image before you `rm` it
RUN cd /opt \
 && wget ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} \
 && tar xzf apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz \
 && rm apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz

# Create a symlink to the jmeter process in a normal bin directory
RUN ln -s /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}/bin/jmeter /usr/local/bin

# Indicate the default command to run
CMD jmeter
```

Finally, there will be questions around where to store data files.  It's better to store data outside the application directory; in a Docker context it's common enough to use short (if non-standard) directory paths like `/data`.  Remember that any file path in a `docker run` command refers to a path in the container, but you need a `docker run -v` bind-mount option (your original `--volume` is equivalent) to make it visible on the host.  That would give you a final command like:

```sh
docker run -v "$PWD:/data" atos/jmeter \
    jmeter -n -t /data/TEST.jmx -l /data/res.jtl
```

Comment: Thank you !! But I have the following error : An error occurred: The file /C:/Program Files/Git/data/TEST.jmx doesn't exist or can't be opened ... I have created the file and I really don't understand why there is this problem ...

Comment: That's a git bash error, change your paths to have an extra leading slash, e.g. `export jmeter_path="//opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin"` or in this case `//data/TEST.jmx`

Comment: Thank you, and I have modified to `docker run -v "$(pwd)":/data my/jmeter \
jmeter -n -t //data/TEST.jmx -l //data/res.jtl` but now I have the error : `An error occurred: The file /data/TEST.jmx doesn't exist or can't be opened` ... Any idea? Really I don't understand anything about this error, and can't find any help on Google ...

Comment: Now you are running Linux in Windows or the other way around? `$(pwd)` doesn't work in Windows.

Comment: Provide the path of .jmx instade of $(pwd).

Your command should be like 
docker run -v "<path of .jmx>":/data my/jmeter \ jmeter -n -t //data/TEST.jmx -l //data/res.jtl